# Android audio automatically getting redirected to earphone

Tags: android

In my Android app, the user gets to specifically select the audio output between internal speakers and earphone. Here is my routine to turn the speaker phone on:

```
static void useSpeaker(Context ctx) {
  AudioManager am = (AudioManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
  am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
}
```

Once the audio is set to speakers, even if you plug in the earphone, the output still goes through the speaker. I have verified on a number of different tablets and phones that this logic works.

However, on one device, once the earphone is plugged in, the audio output automatically switches from speakers to earphone.

I am wondering if there is something else that I need to take care of in the code. Or, is it just this device ignoring my directive? Regards.

Comment: You can react to broadcast `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` and switch to speaker again.

Comment: Tried that. Looks like on some devices, the hardware automatically redirects the audio to earphone once plugged in. You have no control. Regards.